# Dynamic texts from a JSON file into Adobe Animate

Tags: json, jquery-animate, adobe

Newbie here…is there a simple way to load dynamic text fields from an external JSON file (located in the same folder as he Animate project) for later translation?  I have several dynamic text field instances on the stage labeled text_1, text_2, etc.

I followed Chris King's example from 2018 ([Adobe Animate CC- Dynamic text layer pulling from JSON or TXT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860189/adobe-animate-cc-dynamic-text-layer-pulling-from-json-or-txt-file)) but could not get it to work.  For starters, I didn't see where the name of the external JSON file is specified in his code.  But then again, I'm totally new to Java, but was fairly well versed in Flash back in the AS2 days though.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.